# Using dividers on horizontal LinearLayout for pre-honeycomb versions

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-linearlayout, android-3.0-honeycomb, divider

### Background

I'm trying to use the dividers feature for linearLayout, even on older versions of android.

for this, i've found out that [**actionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) has a nice class called  "[**com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout.java)" .

### The problem

it works fine when you use vertical orientation, but if you use horizontal orientation, it doesn't show the dividers on the next case:

when Android is on API 17 and above, and the device uses an RTL language (like Hebrew), and you've set android:supportsRtl="true" . this causes some dividers to show (and some not), and also an empty divider (like a margin) on the left.

Now, I know internal views shouldn't be used, but this is a very essential feature for linearLayouts, and I can't find any nice alternative to it ([**HoloEverywhere**](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) is a very heavy library and isn't granular enough to be used for this).

here's an example of usage:

activity_main.xml

```
<com.example.test.IcsLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFff0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFffff00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFff00ff" />

</com.example.test.IcsLinearLayout>
```

divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <size
        android:height="1dp"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="#FF000000" />

</shape>
```

again, if it's in vertical orientation (and you set the width&height of the children correctly) , it will show the dividers just fine.

### What I've tried

I've tried to make it ignore new versions, and only apply to old ones (by both checking versions and avoid calling new API's functions) but it didn't help.

I've also tried to copy the part of drawDividersHorizontal from the official Android code, as such:

```
  void drawDividersHorizontal(final Canvas canvas)
    {
    final int count=getChildCount();
    boolean isLayoutRtl=false;
    if(VERSION.SDK_INT>=VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
      isLayoutRtl=(getLayoutDirection()&View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)!=0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(i);
      if(child!=null&&child.getVisibility()!=GONE)
        if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i))
          {
          final LayoutParams lp=(LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
          final int position;
          if(isLayoutRtl)
            position=child.getRight()+lp.rightMargin;
          else position=child.getLeft()-lp.leftMargin-mDividerWidth;
          drawVerticalDivider(canvas,position);
          }
      }
    if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count))
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(count-1);
      int position;
      if(child==null)
        {
        if(isLayoutRtl)
          position=getPaddingLeft();
        else position=getWidth()-getPaddingRight()-mDividerWidth;
        }
      else
        {
        final LayoutParams lp=(LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
        if(isLayoutRtl)
          position=child.getLeft()-lp.leftMargin-mDividerWidth;
        else position=child.getRight()+lp.rightMargin;
        }
      drawVerticalDivider(canvas,position);
      }
    }
```

### The question

How do I make it work for horizontal orientation too?

Answer (score 1):

try this sample

```
<com.example.test.IcsLinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@drawable/divider"
android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <View
android:layout_width="2dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="3dip"
android:background="#FFff0000" />
<View
android:layout_width="2dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="3dip"
android:background="#FFff0000" />
<View
android:layout_width="2dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="3dip"
android:background="#FFff0000" />
</com.example.test.IcsLinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution.

Comment: 1.i tried my code and it didn't work. i meant about fixing the IcsLinearLayout of ABS library. didn't mean you'd use my code (it has bugs) 2. it already supposed to put margins for the children automatically according to the size of the divider.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this (tested on an Android api 10 phone (2.3.3 - 2.3.6)) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFff0000" />

<!-- First divider -->
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFffff00" />

<!-- Second divider -->
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFff00ff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It's a workaround but it works !

Comment: Sure it would work, but that's not what i've asking about. i wanted to harness the same power as used on LinearLayout from ICS, to all Android versions... :(